# A contour integration with two indentation

Tags: complex-analysis

I need a help to compute the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-x^3}}dx$ by calculus of residues. All I have proceeded from my side is to determine the contour : [image]

having one indentation at origin($z=0$) and another at $z=1$ and a branch line between them. But how to proceed for further integration along that contour?